# Word for someone who is attracted to people without make-up

Tags: phrase-requests, epithet-requests

I'm wondering what native English speakers call a person (man or woman) who is attracted to a no-make-up look and dislikes it when people wear a high amount of makeup.

I can think of *no-makeup lover* or *not into makeup*. But is there a specific word being used?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148996/discussion-on-question-by-snack-exchange-word-for-someone-who-is-attracted-to-pe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I've never heard a specific word for this.

Comment: I don't believe there is a single word. A native speaker could explain like "attracted to natural beauty" but natural beauty is not just about a face without make-up; so it is not really an answer. _Cosmetiphobia_ was used by a very few people on the net but it appears to be used with the meaning "fear of applying make-up".

Comment: Are you sure that's *cosmet**i**phobia* and not *cosmet**o**phobia*?

Comment: Similarly, is there a word for someone who is **only** attracted to someone **wearing** makeup? Is there one in your language?

Comment: @SnackExchange Both _cosmetophobia_ and _cosmetiphobia_ were coined apparently. The first element before the suffix _-phobia_ takes the form ending with 'o' usually. But they are just rare neologisms made up by some people so it doesn't matter much. It is not the word you are looking for either.